# Accessing @SessionScoped @ManagedBean class in ExternalContext#getSessionMap() returns null

Tags: jsf, managed-bean, session-scope

Iam trying to get object of my SessionScoped managedBean from ManagedBeanUtil class but all iam getting is null.

here is my code:-

```
package com.beas.ui.manager;
@ManagedBean(name = "sessionManager")
@SessionScoped
public class SessionManager implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = -3064514740080155761L;

//..
}

public class ManagedBeanUtil {

public static SessionManager getSessionManager() {

    return (SessionManager) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance()
            .getExternalContext().getSessionMap().get("sessionManager"); // returns null
}
}
```

i don't no what iam doing wrong. can anyone give the suitable solution for this?

Comment: why do you want to access bean in such a way instead of injection ?

Comment: is something wrong with the way iam accessing sessionManager @erencan.

Answer (score 6):

When you access it that "raw" way, it will return `null` when JSF hasn't (auto)created the bean yet.

If you want to make sure that JSF auto-creates the bean, then you should be accessing it by evaluating it as an EL expression via among others [`Application#evaluateExpressionGet()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/faces/application/Application.html#evaluateExpressionGet(javax.faces.context.FacesContext,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Class)):

```
public static SessionManager getSessionManager() {
    FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    return (SessionManager) context.getApplication().evaluateExpressionGet(context, "#{sessionManager}", SessionManager.class);
}
```

However, the canonical (and more declarative) way is to inject it as a `@ManagedProperty` in the target bean (which does under the covers basically the same as above).

```
@ManagedBean
@RequestScoped
public class SomeBean {

    @ManagedProperty("#{sessionManager}")
    private SessionManager sessionManager; // +setter
}
```

---

CDI `@Named`+`@Inject` makes it more clean by not requiring the setter and annotation value.

```
@Named
@RequestScoped
public class SomeBean {

    @Inject
    private SessionManager sessionManager;
}
```

```
@Named
@SessionScoped
public class SessionManager implements Serializable {

}
```

Comment: Sorry for replying so late but sessionManager managed bean is declared in session scope. So we can access managedBean via getSessionMap() method. And it actually work for me but not this time :(

Comment: Hm? Did you read and understood the answer? The first sentence already explains when it would return `null`. And thereafter the answer shows how you can obtain it anyway. Or perhaps you meant to reply on a comment of someone else?

Comment: yeah read your answer. but my concern is why bean isn't created yet it supposed to be. what is wrong with using getSessionMap().

Comment: That can happen when the session scoped JSF managed bean is nowhere referenced in EL via `#{managedBeanName}` beforehand within the same session. When a session scoped JSF managed bean is referenced for the first time in EL, e.g. because it's referenced in a JSF page, then JSF will autocreate the instance and put it in session map with the managed bean name as key. Only after that moment, it will for the remainder of the session be available via the session map the way you initially did. Just solely trying to grab it from the session map won't autocreate the bean instance if not available.